# CSS Failed to Customize the dropdown arrow ▼

Tags: css, dropdown

I can't customize it, he refuses! important
Did I miss something?

[My Dropdown codepen](https://codepen.io/newneo/pen/yLaQerg)

```
.fs-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transition: ease-in 0.15s;
}

.fs-open .fs-arrow {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

With font-family: "dashicons" **Failed**

```
.fs-arrow{
    font-family: "dashicons" !important;
    content: "\f347" !important;
}
```

with font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free"  **Failed**

```
.fs-arrow{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free" !important;
    font-weight:600 !important;
    content: "\f078" !important;
}
```

I already have all FontAwesome included and it is displayed but in **after**

all that is not very pretty ..

```
.fs-arrow:after{
        font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free" !important;
        font-weight:600 !important;
        content: "\f078" !important;
    }
```

[image]
what is this horror..

**EDIT :**

if it helps .. i did this, it's still horrible but centered at least
[image]

they are on top of each other

```
.fs-default > div > span{
    color:#f86c6c;
    top:-4px;
    left:195px;
    margin-bottom:24px;
    right:auto !important;
    width:23px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I have done it using fontawesome:

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/poEOPRK

One of the main thing you are missing in the animation is `transform-origin: center;`

Comment: Hello Mannas Khandelwal can you customize it and show me?
you have the link at the top

Comment: @newneo plz, include the complete CSS for it too, how will I do so if I do not have the CSS.

Comment: @newneo This is how your code looks like https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/poEOPRK But all the images you are showing are different. Either you have not uploaded the complete code of or you are using some external library or javascript.

Comment: no it's not that I may have copied the code incorrectly you already have the page look at the [demo](https://facetwp.com/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/assets/vendor/fSelect/test.html) page and here is the [source code](https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect), I don't see anything special it's even simple

Comment: Now it is working, let me see, you gave incomplete css.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227135/discussion-between-manas-khandelwal-and-newneo).

Comment: I have done it, check it out: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/poEOPRK

Comment: Hi @ManasKhandelwa I just tested again it's a good solution but you inserted an icon in the html which I don't want to do because I want a **pure css solution**, even if I'm good at css in general...it's the devil's arrow ▼ this thing!
thank you again for the effort and help